# use nonfinal variable in Adapter View

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, android-adapter, final

I have a page displaying information about a movie, and a voting system beneath for objects called Trigger objects.  The voting system isn't working, I think because in order to use the Trigger object in the view in the OnClickListener I have to declare the trigger Final, and so it's setting the onclicklistener to the first trigger object, so whatever button I interact with only the first trigger object to be loaded changes.  How can I implement this so that I don't have to use a final variable inside the onclick listener?

**TriggerAdapter.java**

```
...

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        movieDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("movies");
        userDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        adminDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("admin");

        final String mUserId = user.getUid();
        trigger = mTriggers.get(i);

        triggerDB = movieDB.child(mImdbID).child("Triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName());

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.trigger_list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.triggerName = view.findViewById(R.id.triggerName);
            holder.upButton = view.findViewById(R.id.mTriggerButtonUp);
            holder.downButton = view.findViewById(R.id.mTriggerButtonDown);
            holder.total = view.findViewById(R.id.triggerCounter);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.triggerName.setText(trigger.getTriggerName());

        if (mContext instanceof AdminPanelActivity) {
            holder.upButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.downButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    adminDB.child("triggerList").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).removeValue();
                    int i = mTriggers.indexOf(trigger);
                    mTriggers.remove(i);
                    TriggerAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

        if (mContext instanceof MovieActivity) {

            triggerDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Trigger trigger;
                    trigger = dataSnapshot.getValue(Trigger.class);
                    holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(trigger.getTriggerVotesTotal()));
                    holder.upButton.setCount(trigger.getTriggerVotesYes());
                    int downBoats = (trigger.getTriggerVotesTotal() - trigger.getTriggerVotesYes());
                    holder.downButton.setCount(downBoats);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        int userVote = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);

                        if (userVote == 0) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent, null));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent, null));

                            }
                            else {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
                            }

                            neitherButtonIsSelected(holder, trigger, mUserId);
                        }
                        if (userVote == 1) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.votebuttons, null));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent, null));

                            }
                            else {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.votebuttons));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
                            }
                            upButtonIsSelected(holder, trigger, mUserId);
                        }
                        if (userVote == -1) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent, null));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.votebuttons, null));

                            }
                            else {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.votebuttons));
                            }
                            downButtonIsSelected(holder, trigger, mUserId);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(0);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }


        return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView triggerName;
        CounterFab upButton;
        CounterFab downButton;
        TextView total;
    }
    private void neitherButtonIsSelected(final ViewHolder holder, final Trigger trigger, final String mUserId) {


        holder.upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                triggerDB.child("triggerVotesYes").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                        mutableData.setValue(count + 1);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }
                });
                triggerDB.child("triggerVotesTotal").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                        mutableData.setValue(count + 1);

                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }
                });
                userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(1);
            }
        });

        holder.downButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {

                triggerDB.child("triggerVotesTotal").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                        mutableData.setValue(count + 1);

                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    }
                });
                userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(1);
            }
        });
    }

    private void upButtonIsSelected(final ViewHolder holder, final Trigger trigger, final String mUserId) {
        holder.upButton.setOnClickListener(null);
        holder.downButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                triggerDB.child("triggerVotesYes").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                        mutableData.setValue(count - 1);
                        userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(-1);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//                        holder.downButton.getBackground().setAlpha(127);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    private void downButtonIsSelected(final ViewHolder holder, final Trigger trigger, final String mUserId) {
        holder.downButton.setOnClickListener(null);
        holder.upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                triggerDB.child("triggerVotesYes").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                        mutableData.setValue(count + 1);
                        userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(1);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//                        holder.downButton.getBackground().setAlpha(127);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim down your code to the specific block to which you are asking the question.

Comment: ok i trimmed it down to just the getview... I think everything in there is relevant unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

> The voting system isn't working, I think because in order to use the
>   Trigger object in the view in the OnClickListener I have to declare
>   the trigger Final

Is `trigger` an instance field? Then yes, it's value is going to get reset whenever someone executes the on click. Just do the `mTriggers.get(i)` in the onclick. You'll need to make the argument `i` final.

Alternatively, make `trigger` a local final,

```
final Trigger trigger = mTriggers.get(i);
```

Now you can be assured it's value cannot be changed by subsuquent executions of this method.

Comment: nah same problem just through one layer of abstraction, if i is final, mTriggerList.get(i) will be the same for each view, same as if I did final Trigger trigger = mTriggerList.get(i) and passed that trigger into the function.

Comment: Um, no. `mTriggerList.get(i)` will return the trigger for `i`, and `i` is for a specific view.